# How to render a button depending on the state list?

Tags: list, jsf, render

I have a button, which should be disabled if a particular list is empty. And, accordingly, active, if list not empty. When the initial page load button is disabled, because list is empty. And then the list is filled, but the button is still disabled and does not react to this. I put it in a panelGroup, but I do not know where to render it again. In what place I must to insert the attribute "render" or "rendered". And what they should be equal? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
This is my code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="buttonSave">
    <h:commandButton value="#{bean.value}"
        action="mypage" 
        actionListener="#{bean.onSave}"
        disabled="#{empty bean.list}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Are you using ajax anywhere? Code looks fine. Cause of problem is somewhere else. Please provide more context, preferably in flavor of an SSCCE (i.e. copy'n'paste'n'runnable).

Comment: I am using JSF 2.0. Where can I use ajax-request to render panelGroup?

Comment: Yes, OK, you're thus not using Ajax. Is the bean request scoped?

Comment: Thank you very much! I already knew how to solve my problem. I set the attribute "render" to button that fills my list. And from that moment everything worked